My requests to my api working on AWS Elastic Beanstalk are ended at 60 seconds, I want to increase it
My web app is working on load balanced environment on Elastic Beanstalk.
Small portion of my requests are taking more than 60 seconds to complete.
I did the following:

I increased "Connection idle timeout" on Load Balancer Attributes.
I increased "Max execution time" on Configuration tab of Elastic Beanstalk environment.
I restarted app server which is Apache.

But my requests are still ended at 60 seconds.
How to overcome this issue?
I am thinking, maybe rebuilding the environment?

Let observe the flow as follows:
Elastic Load Balancer --> Apache Webserver --> EC2 (with PHP deployment)

You have mentioned that most of your changes are made at the ELB but you still have 60s timeout.
There are places that also have config that you need to check, such as Apache config. You can try with this structure:

Create a folder and a file as follows from your deployment package:

.ebextensions/
  environment.config


Create a httpd.conf file from this example and modify the value of Timeout to be higher than 60.

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 120


Upload it to an S3 bucket and retrieve the file's S3 URI.
Edit the environment.config as follows:

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
          type: S3
          roleName: ec2-s3-access
          buckets: myphp-config
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" :
    mode: "000664"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myphp-config/httpd.conf
    authentication: S3Access

Make sure that the IAM role has IAM permissions to yours S3 bucket that storing the httpd.conf.
There is a 2nd place that you can check is your ElasticBeanstalk php.ini execution time setting which is also can using this file.
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: max_execution_time
    value: 120

Once done, you can re-package your deployment and upload it again to your dev environment and perform testing.

Hello Binh. Thanks for the idea. Thanks to you I remember I overcame this issue before, increasing Apache Timeout. But the problem is that the environment is Load Balanced, so when the EC2 servers change, my edit to configuration file is gone. So, finally, the problem here remains to be editing httpd file dynamically with ebextensions. You gave the example for adding httpd.conf, but there is httpd.conf file already in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, how to edit it dynamically with ebextensions? I think no need for extra file in S3, just editing Timeout value will be enough.
